# Custom Macros not showing as bindable to custom buttons in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-macros

I have a few macros that are working on coworkers machines however when I add them in under my macros I am not able to select them from the list of macros to bind a button in visual studio to execute them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what the root cause of this issue was, however By setting the macro to record and letting it auto create a module let me copy and paste the methods from my custom macro into the newly created module and work without issue.